# An activity without UI displayed sometimes

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity

I am working with someone else code, and have run into a rather strange issue.
Since I am hard pressed on time, I am looking for a way about without re-factoring the code.
I have Activity1 launced first which in turn calls Activity2 and comes back to Activity1.
The problem is I do not want the Activity1 to show as UI during its launch, but show its UI only after Activity 2 is called.
I have tried setting the theme of activity1 dynamically from the acivity using

setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoDisplay);

but it inevitably still displays a blank page without UI elements.
Is there an alternative?

Comment: What's the use of launching 1 before 2? Launch 2, then 1. If needed, you could have some shared methods in 1 and call them from 2 before showing 1.

Comment: Have you tried not setting the content view in onCreate and then call setContentView when onActivityResult is called from Activity B? Or, have your Activity A's parent layout defined with android:visibility="gone" in your XML file and then set it programmatically to View.VISIBLE when returning from the Activity (again, in onActivityResult)

Comment: Thanks! ..i just tried out your suggestions..in both the cases I see a white page with a menubar on the top, I just needed no display ..any ideas?